# TransactionRequiredException thrown by EclipseLink 2.4.1 when using Spring 3.1.3

Tags: java, spring, jpa, eclipselink

i'm trying to setup the following components:

- EclipseLink 2.4.1
- Spring 3.1.3
- Glassfish 3.1.2
- Derby Embedded Database

the stuff is running so far. but as soon as i want to persist something into my JPA context, a `TransactionRequiredException` is thrown:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: 
Exception Description: No transaction is currently active
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.throwCheckTransactionFailedException(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.transaction.EntityTransactionWrapper.checkForTransaction(EntityTransactionWrapper.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.checkForTransaction(EntityManagerImpl.java:1776)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:780)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    at $Proxy439.flush(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240)
    at $Proxy439.flush(Unknown Source)
    at backend.dao.StoredObjectDAO.save(StoredObjectDAO.java:39)
    at backend.service.StorageService.setObjectForKey(StorageService.java:35)
    at backend.controller.StoredObjectController.setObjectForKey(StoredObjectController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:604)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:565)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:688)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:281)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:849)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:746)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1045)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:228)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

the transaction manager is set up as described in various tutorials and even eclipse recognizes the aspectj weaving by indicating the pointcuts with the regarding icons in beside the linenumber pane.
since i'm using the `@Transactional` annotation, i properly set `<tx:annotaion-driven />` to "on".

but still, i keep getting the same exception. does anybody know if there is a particular setting needed when using this constelation of libraries?
please find all necessary files attached below.

thanks,
manu

---

### UPDATE

finally left Spring and used another stack:

- Google Guice (dependency injection)
- Jersey (REST library)
- Eclipse Link (JPA)

i had to go on and this solution was more pragmatic that time.
maybe giving Spring another chance some time.

thank you all for all your inputs anyway! :-)

---

### applicationContext-jpa.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">

    <context:load-time-weaver />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <import resource="applicationContext-dataSource.xml" />

    <bean id="jpaAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
        <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.DerbyPlatform" />
        <property name="showSql" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />



    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaAdapter" />
        <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    </bean>



    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

</beans>
```

### applicationContext-dataSource.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">


    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/backend" />

</beans>
```

### persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="backend" transaction-type="JTA">
        <!-- 
            jta-data-source is only used for the IDE. Spring/Runtime uses the
            data source from applicationContext-dataSource.
        -->
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/backend</jta-data-source>

        <class>backend.model.StoredObject</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

### StoredObjectDAO.java

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class StoredObjectDAO implements IStoredObjectDAO {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Collection<StoredObject> listAll() {
        TypedQuery<StoredObject> query = entityManager.createQuery("select s from StoredObject s", StoredObject.class);
        Collection<StoredObject> results = query.getResultList();
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public void save(StoredObject storedObject) {
        entityManager.persist(storedObject);
        entityManager.flush(); // <---- throws Exception
    }

}
```

Comment: I see  Transactional annotation missing on StoredObjectDAO.save, is that typo?

Comment: `save()` is "inheriting" the `@Transactional` from `StoredObjectDAO` since it was defined there. however, i've already tried to add the annotation for `save()`, but still the same problem. thanks anyway! :)

Answer (score 5):

If you are calling your DAO methods from service classes, avoid annotating DAO methods @Transactional. Instead annotate your Service class methods transactional. The reason behind this is, you may need to call multiple DAO methods under one transaction. This may cause problems if all your DAO methods are transactional. So If you annotate your service method transactional, you can call any number of DAO methods under one transaction.

If any exception occurs, entire transaction will be rollbacked if you annotate service class transactional.

Answer (score 4):

It is missing to use `readonly` attribue and `propagation` mode.
Default `propagation` mode is `REQUIRED`. That's why, your coding will assume as below,

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED)
public Collection<StoredObject> listAll() {
    ......
}
```

**Point** : The `readonly` connection would be thrown exception when the `REQUIRED` propagation mode is used.

**Answer :** If you would like to use `readonly` connection, `propagation` mode will be `SUPPORTS`.

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true, propagation=Propagation.SUPPORTS)
    public Collection<StoredObject> listAll() {
    ......
}
```

For references : [Transaction strategies](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ts1/index.html)

Comment: the readonly-methods were working without any problem. the ones which persist something into JPA caused the exception. thanks any way for your suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

No transaction is currently active ? means did not begin entityTransacton

Can you try

```
@Override
public void save(StoredObject storedObject) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    entityManager.persist(storedObject);
    entityManager.flush(); // <---- throws Exception
}
```

but keep a separate method for begin and commit.

Comment: well, spring should exactly accomplish this by weaving a transaction around the `save()` method. if i try doing like you advise, i get `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring transactions or EJB CMT instead`

Comment: debug it, somewhere transaction is not get started.

Comment: @Stivel he's using Spring's declarative transaction management. manually starting transactions in that context is a huge no-go

Answer (score 2):

Don't you need a provider in the persistence-unit?

Comment: added one. no change :( ... even tried now to switch to hibernate without any improvement too.

Answer (score 2):

As per Spring docs

```
<tx:annotation-driven/> only looks for @Transactional on beans in the same application context it is defined in. 
This means that, if you put <tx:annotation-driven/> in a WebApplicationContext for a DispatcherServlet, it only checks for @Transactional beans in your controllers, and not your services.
```

Please verify, you have configured it properly

Comment: thanks for the input. the component-scan-tag is set up properly :-/

Answer (score 2):

The error seems like EclipseLink is using a EntityTransactionWrapper instead of the JTATransactionWrapper I'd expect if configured to use JTA, as is the case in this post: 
[Spring + Eclipselink + JtaTransactionManager = javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6929309/spring-eclipselink-jtatransactionmanager-javax-persistence-transactionrequ)

You might want to verify that the persistence.xml being used is marked for JTA, and is the one you've shown, as it could be another persistence.xml is picked up on your classpath instead.

Comment: you might try turning on eclipselink logging to get more detail on what Spring might or might not be passing through.  Logging is described here: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Logging

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. unfortunately i had to move on and removed spring completely from my project since the deadline for the component is by mid of this week. using now jersey and google guice for DI without any problems.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the Spring documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations), it describes the default as follows:

> The "proxy-target-class" attribute on the "tx:annotation-driven" element controls what type of transactional proxies are created for classes annotated with the @Transactional annotation. If the proxy-target-class attribute is set to true, then class-based proxies are created. If proxy-target-class is false or if the attribute is omitted, then standard JDK interface-based proxies are created.

Since your case is class-based proxies, then you need to add this attribute like this:

> tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transaction-manager="transactionManager"

You can even lose the attribute:

> transaction-manager="transactionManager"

since it is the default anyways.....!

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. unfortunately i had to move on and removed spring completely from my project. using now jersey and google guice for DI.

Comment: I would strongly suggest Seam over Guice ....! And in case you are using GlassFish then look into CDI and its reference implementation Weld. It is the JEE6 specification for DI

Comment: As for CDI tutorial pointers, please refer to my answer in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13250513/container-testing-of-jar-with-embedded-glassfish-using-gradle-fails/13282722#13282722

Comment: thanks for your comment again. it's the first time i use guice and havent had any problems till now. what are exactly the advantages of using seam over guice?

Answer (score 0):

If you use transaction-type="JTA" then in web container ex: Tomcat, you need to use JOTM to manage transaction and configure it in both Tomcat and Spring.

And more, in file persistence.xml, you need to add the line following:

```
 <properties>

<property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="org.eclipse.persistence.transaction.jotm.JotmTransactionController"/>

</properties>
```