# Container testing of jar with embedded glassfish using gradle fails

Tags: java, jpa, glassfish, gradle, cdi

I am using JUnit and embedded glassfish to test some code using CDI.  This seems fairly straightforward but I must be missing something.  I've created a simple project which demonstrates the problem.

https://github.com/dantwinkler/container-test-embedded-glassfish

This is the stack trace if no parameters are set.  If the domain.xml is specified in the embedded container properties the tests still fail but because it says the test can not be found.  The next step is to try to get things working without gradle to see if that is the culprit.

```
Gradle Worker 1 executing tests.

com.foo.service.TestModelServiceTest STANDARD_ERROR
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:35 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.CommonClassLoaderServiceImpl findDerbyClient
    INFO: Cannot find javadb client jar file, derby jdbc driver will not be available by default.
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:38 AM org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
    SEVERE: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = META-INF/gfprobe-provider.xml
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:javamail:smtp-transport
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.core.ProbeProviderRegistry.registerProbeProvider(ProbeProviderRegistry.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.registerProvider(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.processXMLProbeProviders(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:386)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processProbeProviderXML(MonitoringBootstrap.java:484)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processManifest(MonitoringBootstrap.java:360)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.addProvider(MonitoringBootstrap.java:301)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.verifyModule(MonitoringBootstrap.java:245)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.discoverProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.enableMonitoringForProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:624)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.postConstruct(MonitoringBootstrap.java:176)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:229)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:204)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
        at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
        at com.foo.service.TestModelServiceTest.setup(TestModelServiceTest.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.TypeCastDispatch.dispatch(TypeCastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:53)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ProtocolStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:167)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:277)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomConnection$1.run(ProtocolStack.java:299)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:120)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:116)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:38 AM org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
    SEVERE: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = jersey-gf-server-probe-provider.xml
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:jersey:server-hidden
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.core.ProbeProviderRegistry.registerProbeProvider(ProbeProviderRegistry.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.registerProvider(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.processXMLProbeProviders(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:386)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processProbeProviderXML(MonitoringBootstrap.java:484)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processManifest(MonitoringBootstrap.java:360)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.addProvider(MonitoringBootstrap.java:301)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.verifyModule(MonitoringBootstrap.java:245)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.discoverProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.enableMonitoringForProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:624)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.postConstruct(MonitoringBootstrap.java:176)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:229)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:204)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
        at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
        at com.foo.service.TestModelServiceTest.setup(TestModelServiceTest.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.TypeCastDispatch.dispatch(TypeCastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:53)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ProtocolStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:167)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:277)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomConnection$1.run(ProtocolStack.java:299)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:120)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:116)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:39 AM org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory processXMLProbeProviders
    SEVERE: MNTG0301:Cannot process XML ProbeProvider, xml = jersey-gf-statsprovider-probe-provider.xml
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Provider already mapped glassfish:jersey:server
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.core.ProbeProviderRegistry.registerProbeProvider(ProbeProviderRegistry.java:100)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.registerProvider(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:561)
        at org.glassfish.flashlight.impl.provider.FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.processXMLProbeProviders(FlashlightProbeProviderFactory.java:386)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processProbeProviderXML(MonitoringBootstrap.java:484)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.processManifest(MonitoringBootstrap.java:360)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.addProvider(MonitoringBootstrap.java:301)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.verifyModule(MonitoringBootstrap.java:245)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.discoverProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:188)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.enableMonitoringForProbeProviders(MonitoringBootstrap.java:624)
        at org.glassfish.admin.monitor.MonitoringBootstrap.postConstruct(MonitoringBootstrap.java:176)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.inject(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:131)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.ConstructorCreator.initialize(ConstructorCreator.java:91)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractCreatorImpl.get(AbstractCreatorImpl.java:82)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.SingletonInhabitant.get(SingletonInhabitant.java:67)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.EventPublishingInhabitant.get(EventPublishingInhabitant.java:139)
        at com.sun.hk2.component.AbstractInhabitantImpl.get(AbstractInhabitantImpl.java:78)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.run(AppServerStartup.java:229)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.doStart(AppServerStartup.java:145)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup.start(AppServerStartup.java:136)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishImpl.start(GlassFishImpl.java:79)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:204)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.EJBContainerProviderImpl.createEJBContainer(EJBContainerProviderImpl.java:129)
        at javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(EJBContainer.java:127)
        at com.foo.service.TestModelServiceTest.setup(TestModelServiceTest.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
        at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
        at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:30)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecuter.execute(JUnitTestClassExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(JUnitTestClassProcessor.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:32)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
        at $Proxy2.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.processTestClass(TestWorker.java:103)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.TypeCastDispatch.dispatch(TypeCastDispatch.java:30)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:53)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.WorkerProtocol.handleIncoming(WorkerProtocol.java:31)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ProtocolStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:167)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomStage.handleIncoming(ProtocolStack.java:277)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$BottomConnection$1.run(ProtocolStack.java:299)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:120)
        at org.gradle.messaging.remote.internal.ProtocolStack$ExecuteRunnable.dispatch(ProtocolStack.java:116)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.dispatchMessages(AsyncDispatch.java:132)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch.access$000(AsyncDispatch.java:33)
        at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.AsyncDispatch$1.run(AsyncDispatch.java:72)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:66)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:39 AM org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version <clinit>
    INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 4.3.0.Final
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:43 AM org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry register
    INFO: Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:43 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.AppServerStartup run
    SEVERE: Startup service failed to start : com.sun.enterprise.naming.GlassFishNamingBuilder
    Nov 11, 2012 11:30:43 AM com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.StopServer doExecute
    INFO: Server shutdown initiated
Process 'Gradle Worker 1' finished with exit value 0 (state: SUCCEEDED)
```

The Model

```
package com.foo.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table
public class TestModel implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Long id;
    private String test;

    public TestModel() {
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false)
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

The Service

```
package com.foo.service;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import com.foo.model.TestModel;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Named
@Stateless
public class TestModelService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="TestPersistenceUnit")
    private EntityManager em;

    public void addTest(TestModel test) {

        em.persist(test);
    }

    public void deleteTest(Long testId) {

        TestModel test = em.find(TestModel.class, testId);

        if(test != null) {

            em.remove(test);
        }
    }

}
```

The Service Test

```
package com.foo.service;

import com.foo.model.TestModel;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import javax.ejb.embeddable.EJBContainer;

public class TestModelServiceTest  {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestModelServiceTest.class);

    static private TestModelService testService = null;

    private static EJBContainer container;

    public TestModelServiceTest() throws Exception {

    }

    @BeforeClass
    static public void setup()
        throws IOException, JAXBException
    {
        // domain.xml from http://embedded-glassfish.java.net/domain.xml
        try {
            Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
            props.put(EJBContainer.MODULES, new File("target/classes"));
            props.put(EJBContainer.APP_NAME, "test");

            // Code never gets past this line!
            container = EJBContainer.createEJBContainer(props);

            // Never get to this 
            fail();

            // Get a handle to the service through the context
            testService = (TestModelService)container.getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/TestModelService");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            fail(e.toString());
        }

    }


    @AfterClass
    static public void teardown()
        throws IOException
    {
        if(container != null) {
            container.close();      
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidUser() throws Exception {

        // TestModel a valid basic user
        {
            try {
                TestModel test = new TestModel();

                test.setTest("foo");

                testService.addTest(test);

            } catch(Exception e) {
                fail(e.toString());
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.foo.Account</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

build.gradle

```
// Create Eclipse Project
// Usage: from cmd line in project folder: gradle eclipse

apply plugin: 'java'

// Specify all projects (modules) should use maven central for repositories
allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

jar {
    manifest.attributes['Implementation-Title'] = "test"
}

// Setup all dependencies
// Reference: http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.dsl.DependencyHandler.html
dependencies {

    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.1.4.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:1.0.1.Final'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-jpamodelgen:1.2.0.Final'

    compile fileTree(dir: getGlassfishHomeDir() + File.separator + "glassfish" + File.separator + "modules", include: '*.jar') 

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.apache.derby:derby:10.9.1.0'

    testRuntime 'org.glassfish.main.extras:glassfish-embedded-all:3.1.2'

    testRuntime files(getGlassfishHomeDir() + File.separator + "glassfish"+ File.separator + "lib" + File.separator + "embedded" + File.separator + "glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar")
}

def getGlassfishHomeDir() {
    def glassfishHome = System.getenv('GLASSFISH_HOME')

    if (glassfishHome == null || glassfishHome.length() <= 0)
    {
        msg = "No GLASSFISH_HOME in environment variable. Please set GLASSFISH_HOME to glassfish installation directory"

        println msg

        throw new RuntimeException(msg)
    }

    return glassfishHome
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### First

A major misconception to fix in your code is to assume that a JUnit test can have CDI beans injected.... No, JUnit tests can NOT have CDI beans injected EXCEPT via http://arquillian.org/invasion/ which I am not familiar with.

#### Second

The typical way to use CDI within GlassFish-Weld is [within a servlet as explained in this documentation of Weld](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#d0e4697). Please refer to [this presentation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lZNxzZLT2T4&feature=related) along with [its slides](http://www.slideshare.net/agoncal/to-inject-or-not-to-inject-cdi-is-the-question?ref=http://antoniogoncalves.org/2011/05/23/to-inject-or-not-to-inject-cdi-is-the-question/) for a perfect explanation. And please refer to [this presentation](http://zeroturnaround.com/modal/?publication=20) for an example.

After watching presentations you can get the Managed Beans specifications [JSR-316](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/managed_beans-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/) as well as the famous CDI specifications [JSR-299](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/web_beans-1.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

#### Third

Yet your JUnit test the way it is now can be a legitimate test for your TestModelService stateless EJB using JNDI lookup by following these steps:

1. Make sure you added the jar file "glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar" as an external library while it is at its original place "...glassfish\lib\embedded", thus don't copy it into your project. Doing this step - implicitly - makes the EJBContainer points to your locally installed glassfish domain.xml in your folder ...\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml without you copying it into your project resources.
2. Make sure you are using the persistence.xml file you have on github not the one you have on this post. The one on github has a JTA transaction type pointing to your local Derby DB which is the right transaction type to access a container managed Entity Bean "TestModel". Also you can change the property: hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" to become "create-drop".
3. In the persistence.xml file (on github) change the property exclude-unlisted-classes>true into exclude-unlisted-classes>false
4. Delete this line in your JUnit test:

   > props.put("org.glassfish.ejb.embedded.glassfish.web.http.port","");
5. Delete this line in your JUnit test as well

   > ctx = container.getContext();
6. Right before this line in your JUnit test

   > testService.addTest(test);

   insert this this line:

   > TestModelService testService = (TestModelService)container.getContext().lookup("java:global/classes/TestModelService");
7. Run test.

Comment: Updated project to be correct but the fundamental problem is that the code never makes it past the createEJBContainer step so I never got around to fixing the other parts of the code (CDI lookup, etc).  I removed the domain.xml and added glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar from my glassfish install to the classpath but still no soup.

Comment: The real problem I was having was not using the glassfish-embedded-static-shell.jar.  The rest was just configuration.  After trying to get the embedded glassfish woking for a bit I decided to try arquillian which was MUCH easier and more flexible (I believe the final problem was the test resources configuration but I'll never really know for sure).  https://github.com/dantwinkler/arquillian-test-embedded-glassfish